# Error install Maven in Eclipse

Tags: java

I don't know why maven install error in Eclipse, the following picture: [image]

Thank all!

Comment: Are you at work? If you're in a company network, you might need to configure your proxy settings.

Comment: No, i am a student. You can tell me How to change configure proxy setting? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the .m2 folder and a file called settings.xml Replace the host and port with your own university settings.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd"> 
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>myproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>ENTER PROXY HERE!!!!</host>
      <port>ENTER PORT HERE!!!!</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|ibiblio.org</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```